# How to toggle easily between the AMD Catalyst driver and the open-source Radeon driver?

Tags: drivers, radeon, gpu, catalyst, opencl

I've got an AMD Radeon R9 270X that works very well with the open-source Radeon driver.

However, I am going to occasionally be using an OpenCL application that requires the proprietary Catalyst drivers to function correctly. Is there a way to install the Catalyst drivers yet only use them when I explicitly choose?

Can this be done with a separate Grub menu entry, and if so, how?

Comment: It is possible to do in various ways, but why not always use fglrx?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure This is the thing you are looking for or not. But when I was trying to change the source of my graphics drive I did it form the software and updates and then additional drivers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some month ago, I ask a pretty similar question in ubuntuforum.org, check if it correspond to your need. Not sure is enough easy, but maybe it can be improved/corrected.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278560&p=13289074#post13289074